# What to look for when buying cyclo-cross or road bike under 600eu/650usd?

Tags: road-bike, cyclocross, price

I really want a fast bicycle, that I could use in winter, summer, rain & snow to commute to work. After some research I found out that there is a cool option of cyclo-cross bikes that are build for speed, but can have better tires, mud protection... (winter/rain).

I would use bike mainly to commute to work, usually would ride bicycle on city roads (no off-road or mountain driving). Danish weather is usually moody (rain, little ice here and there) therefore I want something that could have more durable and stable tires.

So again, i came across cyclo-cross bikes and now I was wondering if it is possible to buy a good one under 600eur. Talked with colleagues that have great bikes and they started talking about gears, breaks, handles... and in the end of conversation they summed up that the bike will cost at-least 1500eur.

The thing is, it would be my first 'good' bike and I am not going to go pro or whatever (just commute in different weather). So I decided that I can only spent up 600eur and then I wonder what is the most important things to look for in the bike.

I appreciate any suggestions, tips, help or direction where I should look for bikes to buy/order. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4):

Cyclocross is a type of bike race, which means that most true cyclocross bikes will be expensive, as they are built to win races. You won't find much for that price range if you buy new. But racers are always looking to go faster and get new gear, so consider getting a used bike. You should be able to find a very good used bike for that price.

Also consider looking at touring bikes. They are built quite similar to cyclocross bikes. Except that they are built at little stronger because they are built to carry more baggage. They also have mounting holes for racks which will come in useful for commuting. Many cyclocross bikes don't have the ability to mount racks because racks aren't used for racing.

Comment: You may be right, maybe I should look at used bikes. I really want a cyclo-cross. I don't really need rack, i just have a tiny backpack with my laptop :)

Comment: As well as touring bikes, the Op might also consider bikes described as Audax bikes. I think if he did go for a pure cyclocross bike, he might want to look at changing tyres, for example, if his use was going to be entirely on-road.

Comment: Some cyclocross bikes also don't have much accommodation for fenders, which some would say is practically required for commuting in rain and winter. Touring and audux bikes are basically the same as cyclocross bikes except much better suited to commuting.

Comment: thanks, I never heard about audux bikes before. I will surely look into them :) thanks

Comment: Most race-bred cross bikes probably don't have fender and rack mounts, aside from the Jake line from Kona.

Answer (score 4):

Good answer from Kibbee +1
I just have a bit more to add

Yes a CX makes an excellent commuter. 
It is stable and yet is efficient on the road. 
You just swap out the tires.

I have purchased 2 used CX bikes.
This is the end of CX season so you find some good used values. 
High end bikes are the best values as those are the people churning bikes but they are not going to give them away. 
Even used your $650 price point is just too low. 
Most racers are on $2000+ bikes and at $2000 new you can get it used for like $800. 
Then you are going to add tires most likely need chain, cassette, ... so now you are into it for like $900 to $1200. 
You got a great bike but not at $650.

A racer that buys a $1200 bike new is on a budget and they are likely to ride the bike for a number of years.  These are the guys/girls are more likely to buy used and ride the bike for a number of years.

What you need to look for is the guy / girl that bought a $1200 bike new thinking they were going to race and never did.  It happens but you need to be patient.

A couple years ago I found a $1200 CX single speed that I picked up used $400 and then put $200 into it.

The problem is CX is not likely to have mounts for fenders / racks.

You do find a style of bike that is CX like but not designed for race and comes with mounts.  They call them commuters, urban, city, or light touring.  The Trek CrossRip is a good example and comes in closer to your price point.

So if you open up to any urban / commuter type bike that will take 35mm tires then you have a lot of options.  At $650 new you can even some decent components.  If you want a good fast commuter then at more like $850 - $1000 new you are going go find something nicer and if you put a lot of miles on it is going to cost about the same.

[CX](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/28528/cyclocross-for-road-bike-type-of-routes-increased-risk-of-injury/28529#28529)

Comment: Thanks that is what I was hearing from my friends. Which is upsetting. I tried local web markets, sadly its barely impossible to find good used bikes. :(

Comment: May I ask where you live?

Comment: Denmark. Rainy, windy, but good bike roads

Comment: If you have good bike roads then just put a good 28mm tire on a (used) road bike.  If you are over 200 lbs then not a good option.